# running mock test for angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write test case for the [Angular UI](https://github.com/mchengal/ANNE-stack/blob/master/public/app/services/datacontext.js) . I just learned angular and tried test case with one controller which is working for me. But the below code is not working for me.

```
describe('controller admin parts ->', function() {
    var scope, vm, $httpBackend, createController;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector) {

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/getAllNodes').
        respond({"responseData": [
            {
                "n": {
                    "id": "14",
                    "data": {
                        "name": "StageConfig",
                        "stageArray": "[{\"name\":\"Floor Plan Options\",\"order\":1,\"cardinality\":\"M\",\"description\":\"3\"},{\"name\":\"Community\",\"order\":2,\"cardinality\":\"O\",\"description\":\"1\"},{\"name\":\"Floor Plan\",\"order\":3,\"cardinality\":\"O\",\"description\":\"2\"}]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]});

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        createController = function() {
            return $controller('routes', { $scope: scope });
        };

    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    // tests for stage controller


});
```

I am getting error "Unsatisfied request'. Can someone help me what I am doing wrong here. It will be really helpful. I am trying to execute all the function mentioned in [this](https://github.com/mchengal/ANNE-stack/blob/master/public/app/services/datacontext.js) file